# Very slow framerate and constant crashing (display drivers stopped working) in MKX?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

Very slow framerate and constant crashing (display drivers stopped working) in MKX?  This is constantly happening. I have a decent gaming rig and even on all the low settings it seems to be running slow. Are there any fixes for this?

Comment: What is your graphics card? Do you have the latest driver installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tricks I found (for quad core system): [link](http://steamcommunity.com/app/307780/discussions/0/618459405709324735/)

1. Find MK10.exe in the Details tab of Task Manager

[image]

2. Right click, select "Set Affinity" (requires Admin)

[image]

3. Deselect 1 CPU, and ONLY ONE

[image]

Run the game. You should notice a huge significant boost to your fps and the absence of crashes.

Comment: This is assuming they have more than one CPU

Comment: I don't know who would buy MKX thinking 1 cpu alone could handle it.

Comment: @hotlinecalifornia "Core" pls, not CPU. No gaming rig has more than 1 CPU, that's only useful for servers.

Comment: @kevin Sorry, I meant it as who would buy a next-gen game thinking they could get by on a cpu and an integrated graphics chip.  Having a dedicated graphics card is a must for these kinds of games.